# sql - select different value of a max value nested query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Trying to obtain the Userid value in a row where the max(DateOccurred) was found. I'm getting lost in all these sub-queries.

I'm using SQL Server 2008.

NOTE: Need to return single value since part of another larger query in a SELECT statement.

Example of how I obtain max date (which works); but now I need the userid associated with this subquery max date.

```
    (

    SELECT MAX(LC.[Date]) 

    FROM table_LC LC LEFT JOIN table_LM LM ON LC.[c] = LM.[c] AND LC.[L] = LM.[L]

    WHERE LM.[c] = LC.[c] AND LM.[L] = LC.[L] AND LC.[LC] = 'ABCDEF'

    ) as [ABCDEF_Date],
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot see your whole query, but you probably want to use a window function instead:

```
max(case when lc.lc = 'ABCDEF' then lc.[DATE] end) over () as maxdate
```

This may not be exactly right.  It is hard to say without seeing the rest of the query.

Getting the user id would use similar logic.

EDIT:

You can also get the same effect by putting this in the `from` clause (it is not correlated):

```
from . . . cross join
     (select top 1 lc.[Date], lc.id
      FROM table_LC LC LEFT JOIN
           table_LM LM
           ON LC.[c] = LM.[c] AND LC.[L] = LM.[L]
      WHERE LM.[c] = LC.[c] AND LM.[L] = LC.[L] AND LC.[LC] = 'ABCDEF'
      order by lc.[date] desc
     ) as ABCDEF_Date
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this sub query -

```
(SELECT Userid,
        Date
FROM   (SELECT Userid, Date FROM table_LC) b
WHERE  date = (SELECT MAX(LC.[Date]) 
FROM table_LC LC LEFT JOIN table_LM LM ON LC.[c] = LM.[c] AND LC.[L] = LM.[L]
WHERE LM.[c] = LC.[c] AND LM.[L] = LC.[L] AND LC.[LC] = 'ABCDEF'))
```

Answer (score 0):

A GROUP BY clause lets you SELECT additional non-aggregated columns.

I assumed the "user ID" field is in the LC table, but it could just as easily be in the LM table.

```
SELECT
    LC.[UserID]
    , MAX(LC.[Date]) 

FROM
    table_LC LC
    LEFT JOIN table_LM LM ON 
        LC.[c] = LM.[c] AND LC.[L] = LM.[L]

WHERE LM.[c] = LC.[c] AND LM.[L] = LC.[L] AND LC.[LC] = 'ABCDEF'

GROUP BY LC.[UserID]
```

@Gordon mentioned another good approach using SELECT TOP 1 combined with ORDER BY.

```
SELECT TOP 1
    LC.[UserID]
    , LC.[Date]

FROM
    table_LC LC
    LEFT JOIN table_LM LM ON 
        LC.[c] = LM.[c] AND LC.[L] = LM.[L]

WHERE LC.[LC] = 'ABCDEF'

ORDER BY LC.[Date] DESC
```